# c# strange datatable nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, datatable

```
foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
    dt_final.ImportRow(row);
foreach (DataRow row in dttemp1.Rows)
    dt_final.ImportRow(row);
```

i am getting this exception on the LAST line here

when i check the contents of `row` are NOT null

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is it possible that dt_final or dttemp or dttemp1 are null?

Comment: Obviously one of your variables you access is not set to a valid object reference. Maybe its dt_final, maybe its somewhere in the function ImportRow. Hard to guess from here.

Comment: @everyone if dt_final were null then i would get this exception on the 2nd line, not on the last

Comment: Honestly, instead of having everyone guess, why not just set a breakpoint and run the thing in debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullReferenceException` occurs usually when you try to invoke a member or method on a null object (in other words, when you use the . operator on something that is null).  My best guess is that `dt_final` or perhaps `dttemp1` as other users have suggested is null.

Comment: if dt_final were null then i would get this exception on the 2nd line, not on the last

Comment: Not necessarily. If dttemp.Rows is empty, the first for loop won't run.  This can be a particularly tricky exception.  Many times, you need to carefully trace your code step by step to track down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`dt_final` is definitely null, just because nothing else can be. The question is why it throws error only at last line. Reason is that `dttemp.Rows` is empty and first `foreach` is not executed.